# My desktop has pear os. I want to install Lubuntu from USB instea

Tags: boot

My PC has Pear OS installed and I would like to install Lubuntu instead. I cannot boot from the USB stick (on which Lubuntu is installed). Any suggestions as to how to boot from the USB gratefully received. (I have changed the boot order in BIOS to USB FDD as the first device to boot. It still boots up as Pear OS.) Thanks, John.

Answer (score 0):

try pressing f12 (on most devices) and select USB, I've had many computers that seem to completely ignore the boot order and just boot straight from the hdd

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately I have tried this but it still just boots up as Pear OS.